# Javascript will not pull php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calc</title>

<?php
$isop = 1;
$megp = 1;
$mexp = 1;
$morp = 1;
$nocp = 1;
$pyep = 1;
$trip = 1;
$zydp = 1;
?> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="calceve.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>

var iso = "<?php = $isop; ?>";
var meg = "<?php = $megp; ?>";
var mex = "<?php = $mexp; ?>";
var mor = "<?php = $morp; ?>";
var noc = "<?php = $nocp; ?>";
var pye = "<?php = $pyep; ?>";
var tri = "<?php = $trip; ?>";
var zyd = "<?php = $zydp; ?>";
```

The javascript wont grab the php variables. Im trying to make it so that I can use javascript to edit the php variable everyonce in a while as Eve online prices change, and have the javascript pull the php variables to use in the calculator.

FULL Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Str8nge Brew Calculator</title>

<?php
$isop = 1;
$megp = 1;
$mexp = 1;
$morp = 1;
$nocp = 1;
$pyep = 1;
$trip = 1;
$zydp = 1;
?> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="calceve.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="12%"><p>Isogen</p></td>
    <td width="24%"><input type="text" id="uiso" /></td>
    <td width="14%" id="isoq"></td>
    <td width="50%" id="isocash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Megacyte</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="umeg" /></td>
    <td id="megq"></td>
    <td id="megcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Mexallon</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="umex" /></td>
    <td id="mexq"></td>
    <td id="mexcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Morphite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="umor" /></td>
    <td id="morq"></td>
    <td id="morcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Nocxium</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="unoc" /></td>
    <td id="nocq"></td>
    <td id="noccash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Pyerite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="upye" /></td>
    <td id="pyeq"></td>
    <td id="pyecash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Tritanium</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="utri" /></td>
    <td id="triq"></td>
    <td id="tricash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Zydrine</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uzyd" /></td>
    <td id="zydq"></td>
    <td id="zydcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>--------------</td>
    <td>--------------</td>
    <td>--------------</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="12%"><p>Veldspar</p></td>
    <td width="24%"><input type="text" id="uvel" /><input type="text"  id="uvel5" placeholder="Concentrated" /><input type="text" id="uvel10" placeholder="Dense" /></td>
    <td width="14%"><p id="velq"></p><p id="velq5"></p><p id="velq10"></p></td>
    <td id="velcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Scordite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="usco" /><input type="text" id="usco5" placeholder="Condensed" /><input type="text" id="usco10" placeholder="Massive" /></td>
    <td><p id="scoq"></p><p id="scoq5"></p><p id="scoq10"></p></td>
    <td id="scocash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Pyroxeres</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="upyr" /><input type="text" id="upyr5" placeholder="Solid" /><input type="text" id="upyr10" placeholder="Viscous" /></td>
    <td><p id="pyrq"></p><p id="pyrq5"></p><p id="pyrq10"></p></td>
    <td id="pyrcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Plaglioclase</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="upla" /><input type="text" id="upla5" placeholder="Azure" /><input type="text" id="upla10" placeholder="Rich" /></td>
    <td><p id="plaq"></p><p id="plaq5"></p><p id="plaq10"></p></td>
    <td id="placash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Omber</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uomb" /><input type="text" id="uomb5" placeholder="Silvery" /><input type="text" id="uomb10" placeholder="Golden" /></td>
    <td><p id="ombq"></p><p id="ombq5"></p><p id="ombq10"></p></td>
    <td id="ombcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Kernite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uker" /><input type="text" id="uker5" placeholder="Luminous" /><input type="text" id="uker10" placeholder="Fiery" /></td>
    <td><p id="kerq"></p><p id="kerq5"></p><p id="kerq10"></p></td>
    <td id="kercash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Jaspet</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ujas" /><input type="text" id="ujas5" placeholder="Pure" /><input type="text" id="ujas10" placeholder="Pristine" /></td>
    <td><p id="jasq"></p><p id="jasq5"></p><p id="jasq10"></p></td>
    <td id="jascash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Hemorphite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uhem" /><input type="text" id="uhem5" placeholder="Vivid" /><input type="text" id="uhem10" placeholder="Radient" /></td>
    <td><p id="hemq"></p><p id="hemq5"></p><p id="hemq10"></p></td>
    <td id="hemcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Hedbergite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uhed" /><input type="text" id="uhed5" placeholder="Vitric" /><input type="text" id="uhed10" placeholder="Glazed" /></td>
    <td><p id="hedq"></p><p id="hedq5"></p><p id="hedq10"></p></td>
    <td id="hedcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Gneiss</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ugne" /><input type="text" id="ugne5" placeholder="Iridescent" /><input type="text" id="ugne10" placeholder="Prismatic" /></td>
    <td><p id="gneq"></p><p id="gneq5"></p><p id="gneq10"></p></td>
    <td id="gnecash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Dark Orchre</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="udar" /><input type="text" id="udar5" placeholder="Onyx" /><input type="text" id="udar10" placeholder="Obsidian" /></td>
    <td><p id="darq"></p><p id="darq5"></p><p id="darq10"></p></td>
    <td id="darcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Crokite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ucro" /><input type="text" id="ucro5" placeholder="Sharp" /><input type="text" id="ucro10" placeholder="Crystalline" /></td>
    <td><p id="croq"></p><p id="croq5"></p><p id="croq10"></p></td>
    <td id="crocash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Spodumain</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uspo" /><input type="text" id="uspo5" placeholder="Bright" /><input type="text" id="uspo10" placeholder="Gleaming" /></td>
    <td><p id="spoq"></p><p id="spoq5"></p><p id="spoq10"></p></td>
    <td id="spocash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Bistot</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ubis" /><input type="text" id="ubis5" placeholder="Triclinic" /><input type="text" id="ubis10" placeholder="Monoclinic" /></td>
    <td><p id="bisq"></p><p id="bisq5"></p><p id="bisq10"></p></td>
    <td id="biscash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Arkanor</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uark" /><input type="text" id="uark5" placeholder="Crimson" /><input type="text" id="uark10" placeholder="Prime" /></td>
    <td><p id="arkq"></p><p id="arkq5"></p><p id="arkq10"></p></td>
    <td id="arkcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Mercoxit</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="umer" /><input type="text" id="umer5" placeholder="Magma" /><input type="text" id="umer10" placeholder="Vitreous" /></td>
    <td><p id="merq"></p><p id="merq5"></p><p id="merq10"></p></td>
    <td id="mercash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="sub"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><p>Total</p></td>
    <td id="totalcash"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="sub3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:none;" id="admin">
  <tr>
    <td width="12%"><p>Isogen</p></td>
    <td width="24%"><input type="text" id="uisoa" /></td>
    <td width="14%" id="isoqc">116.99</td>
    <td width="50%" id="isocash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Megacyte</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="umega" /></td>
    <td id="megqc">2029.87</td>
    <td id="megcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Mexallon</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="umexa" /></td>
    <td id="mexqc">33.56</td>
    <td id="mexcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Morphite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="umora" /></td>
    <td id="morqc">6895.29</td>
    <td id="morcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Nocxium</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="unoca" /></td>
    <td id="nocqc">684.26</td>
    <td id="noccash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Pyerite</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="upyea" /></td>
    <td id="pyeqc">11.24</td>
    <td id="pyecash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Tritanium</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="utria" /></td>
    <td id="triqc">5.16</td>
    <td id="tricash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Zydrine</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uzyda" /></td>
    <td id="zydqc">738.98</td>
    <td id="zydcash"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="sub2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

var iso = "<?php = $isop; ?>";
var meg = "<?php = $megp; ?>";
var mex = "<?php = $mexp; ?>";
var mor = "<?php = $morp; ?>";
var noc = "<?php = $nocp; ?>";
var pye = "<?php = $pyep; ?>";
var tri = "<?php = $trip; ?>";
var zyd = "<?php = $zydp; ?>";
alert(2);
var vel = (1000 * tri) / 333
var sco = ((833 * tri) + (416 * pye)) / 333
var pyr = ((844 * tri) + (59 * pye) + (120 * mex) + (11 * noc)) / 333
var pla = ((256 * tri) + (512 * pye) + (256 * mex)) /333
var omb = ((307 * tri) + (123 * pye) + (307 * iso)) / 500
var ker = ((386 * tri) + (773 * mex) + (386 * iso)) / 400
var jas = ((259 * tri) + (259 * pye) + (518 * mex) + (259 * noc) + (8 * zyd)) / 500
var hem = ((212 * tri) + (212 * iso) + (424 * noc) + (28 * zyd)) / 500
var hed = ((708 * iso) + (354 * noc) + (32 * zyd)) / 500
var gne = ((171 * tri) + (171 * mex) + (343 * iso) + (171 * zyd)) / 400
var dar = ((250 * tri) + (500 * noc) + (250 * zyd)) / 400
var cro = ((331 * tri) + (331 * noc) + (663 * zyd)) / 250
var spo = ((700 * tri) + (140 * pye) + (140 * meg)) / 250
var bis = ((170 * pye) + (341 * zyd) + (170 * meg)) / 200
var ark = ((300 * tri) + (166 * zyd) + (333 * meg)) /200
var mer = (530 * mor) / 250
function createButton(context, func){
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "Submit";
    button.onclick = onClick;
    context.appendChild(button);
}
function createButton3(context, func){
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "Submit";
    button.onclick = onClick3;
    context.appendChild(button);
}
function createButton2(context, func){
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "Change";
    button.onclick = onClick2;
    context.appendChild(button);
}
window.onload = function(){
    alert(3);
    document.getElementById('isoq').innerHTML = iso;
    document.getElementById('megq').innerHTML = meg;
    document.getElementById('mexq').innerHTML = mex;
    document.getElementById('morq').innerHTML = mor;
    document.getElementById('nocq').innerHTML = noc;
    document.getElementById('pyeq').innerHTML = pye;
    document.getElementById('triq').innerHTML = tri;
    document.getElementById('zydq').innerHTML = zyd;
    alert(4);
    document.getElementById('velq').innerHTML = vel;
    document.getElementById('scoq').innerHTML = sco;
    document.getElementById('pyrq').innerHTML = pyr;
    document.getElementById('plaq').innerHTML = pla;
    document.getElementById('ombq').innerHTML = omb;
    document.getElementById('kerq').innerHTML = ker;
    document.getElementById('jasq').innerHTML = jas;
    document.getElementById('hemq').innerHTML = hem;
    document.getElementById('hedq').innerHTML = hed;
    document.getElementById('gneq').innerHTML = gne;
    document.getElementById('darq').innerHTML = dar;
    document.getElementById('croq').innerHTML = cro;
    document.getElementById('spoq').innerHTML = spo;
    document.getElementById('bisq').innerHTML = bis;
    document.getElementById('arkq').innerHTML = ark;
    document.getElementById('merq').innerHTML = mer;
    alert(5);
    createButton(document.getElementById('sub'), function(){
        highlight(this.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
        // Example of different context, copied function etc
        // createButton(this.parentNode, this.onclick);
    });
    createButton3(document.getElementById('sub2'), function(){
        highlight(this.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
        // Example of different context, copied function etc
        // createButton(this.parentNode, this.onclick);
    });
    createButton2(document.getElementById('sub3'), function(){
        highlight(this.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
        // Example of different context, copied function etc
        // createButton(this.parentNode, this.onclick);
    });
    alert(5.1);
}
alert(6);
function onClick(){
var aiso = document.getElementById('uiso').value;
var ameg = document.getElementById('umeg').value;
var amex = document.getElementById('umex').value;
var amor = document.getElementById('umor').value;
var anoc = document.getElementById('unoc').value;
var apye = document.getElementById('upye').value;
var atri = document.getElementById('utri').value;
var azyd = document.getElementById('uzyd').value;
alert(7);
var avel = document.getElementById('uvel').value;
var avel5 = (document.getElementById('uvel5').value * 1.05);
var avel10 = (document.getElementById('uvel10').value * 1.1);

var asco = document.getElementById('usco').value;
var asco5 = (document.getElementById('usco5').value * 1.05);
var asco10 = (document.getElementById('usco10').value * 1.1);

var apyr = document.getElementById('upyr').value;
var apyr5 = (document.getElementById('upyr5').value * 1.05);
var apyr10 = (document.getElementById('upyr10').value * 1.1);

var apla = document.getElementById('upla').value;
var apla5 = (document.getElementById('upla5').value * 1.05);
var apla10 = (document.getElementById('upla10').value * 1.1);

var aomb = document.getElementById('uomb').value;
var aomb5 = (document.getElementById('uomb5').value * 1.05);
var aomb10 = (document.getElementById('uomb10').value * 1.1);

var aker = document.getElementById('uker').value;
var aker5 = (document.getElementById('uker5').value * 1.05);
var aker10 = (document.getElementById('uker10').value * 1.1);

var ajas = document.getElementById('ujas').value;
var ajas5 = (document.getElementById('ujas5').value * 1.05);
var ajas10 = (document.getElementById('ujas10').value * 1.1);

var ahem = document.getElementById('uhem').value;
var ahem5 = (document.getElementById('uhem5').value * 1.05);
var ahem10 = (document.getElementById('uhem10').value * 1.1);

var ahed = document.getElementById('uhed').value;
var ahed5 = (document.getElementById('uhed5').value * 1.05);
var ahed10 = (document.getElementById('uhed10').value * 1.1);

var agne = document.getElementById('ugne').value;
var agne5 = (document.getElementById('ugne5').value * 1.05);
var agne10 = (document.getElementById('ugne10').value * 1.1);

var adar = document.getElementById('udar').value;
var adar5 = (document.getElementById('udar5').value * 1.05);
var adar10 = (document.getElementById('udar10').value * 1.1);

var acro = document.getElementById('ucro').value;
var acro5 = (document.getElementById('ucro5').value * 1.05);
var acro10 = (document.getElementById('ucro10').value * 1.1);

var aspo = document.getElementById('uspo').value;
var aspo5 = (document.getElementById('uspo5').value * 1.05);
var aspo10 = (document.getElementById('uspo10').value * 1.1);

var abis = document.getElementById('ubis').value;
var abis5 = (document.getElementById('ubis5').value * 1.05);
var abis10 = (document.getElementById('ubis10').value * 1.1);

var aark = document.getElementById('uark').value;
var aark5 = (document.getElementById('uark5').value * 1.05);
var aark10 = (document.getElementById('uark10').value * 1.1);

var amer = document.getElementById('umer').value;
var amer5 = (document.getElementById('umer5').value * 1.05);
var amer10 = (document.getElementById('umer10').value * 1.1);
alert(8);
var tiso = iso * aiso;
var tmeg = meg * ameg;
var tmex = mex * amex;
var tmor = mor * amor;
var tnoc = noc * anoc;
var tpye = pye * apye;
var ttri = tri * atri;
var tzyd = zyd * azyd;
alert(9);
var tvel = vel * avel;
var tvel5 = vel * avel5;
var tvel10 = vel * avel10;

var tsco = sco * asco;
var tsco5 = sco * asco5;
var tsco10 = sco * asco10;

var tpyr = pyr * apyr;
var tpyr5 = pyr * apyr5;
var tpyr10 = pyr * apyr10;

var tpla = pla * apla;
var tpla5 = pla * apla5;
var tpla10 = pla * apla10;

var tomb = omb * aomb;
var tomb5 = omb * aomb5;
var tomb10 = omb * aomb10;

var tker = ker * aker;
var tker5 = ker * aker5;
var tker10 = ker * aker10;

var tjas = jas * ajas;
var tjas5 = jas * ajas5;
var tjas10 = jas * ajas10;

var them = hem * ahem;
var them5 = hem * ahem5;
var them10 = hem * ahem10;

var thed = hed * ahed;
var thed5 = hed * ahed5;
var thed10 = hed * ahed10;

var tgne = gne * agne;
var tgne5 = gne * agne5;
var tgne10 = gne * agne10;

var tdar = dar * adar;
var tdar5 = dar * adar5;
var tdar10 = dar * adar10;

var tcro = cro * acro;
var tcro5 = cro * acro5;
var tcro10 = cro * acro10;

var tspo = spo * aspo;
var tspo5 = spo * aspo5;
var tspo10 = spo * aspo10;

var tbis = bis * abis;
var tbis5 = bis * abis5;
var tbis10 = bis * abis10;

var tark = ark * aark;
var tark5 = ark * aark5;
var tark10 = ark * aark10;

var tmer = mer * amer;
var tmer5 = mer * amer5;
var tmer10 = mer * amer10;

var totalc = tiso + tmeg + tmex + tmor + tnoc + tpye + ttri + tzyd + tvel + tsco + tpyr + tpla + tomb + tker + tjas + them + thed + tgne + tdar + tcro + tspo + tbis + tark + tmer + tvel5 + tsco5 + tpyr5 + tpla5 + tomb5 + tker5 + tjas5 + them5 + thed5 + tgne5 + tdar5 + tcro5 + tspo5 + tbis5 + tark5 + tmer5 + tvel10 + tsco10 + tpyr10 + tpla10 + tomb10 + tker10 + tjas10 + them10 + thed10 + tgne10 + tdar10 + tcro10 + tspo10 + tbis10 + tark10 + tmer10;
alert(11);
document.getElementById('isocash').innerHTML = tiso;
document.getElementById('megcash').innerHTML = tmeg;
document.getElementById('mexcash').innerHTML = tmex;
document.getElementById('morcash').innerHTML = tmor;
document.getElementById('noccash').innerHTML = tnoc;
document.getElementById('pyecash').innerHTML = tpye;
document.getElementById('tricash').innerHTML = ttri;
document.getElementById('zydcash').innerHTML = tzyd;
alert(12);
document.getElementById('velcash').innerHTML = (tvel + tvel5 + tvel10);
document.getElementById('scocash').innerHTML = (tsco + tsco5 + tsco10);
document.getElementById('pyrcash').innerHTML = (tpyr + tpyr5 + tpyr10);
document.getElementById('placash').innerHTML = (tpla + tpla5 + tpla10);
document.getElementById('ombcash').innerHTML = (tomb + tomb5 + tomb10);
document.getElementById('kercash').innerHTML = (tker + tker5 + tker10);
document.getElementById('jascash').innerHTML = (tjas + tjas5 + tjas10);
document.getElementById('hemcash').innerHTML = (them + them5 + them10);
document.getElementById('hedcash').innerHTML = (thed + thed5 + thed10);
document.getElementById('gnecash').innerHTML = (tgne + tgne5 + tgne10);
document.getElementById('darcash').innerHTML = (tdar + tdar5 + tdar10);
document.getElementById('crocash').innerHTML = (tcro + tcro5 + tcro10);
document.getElementById('spocash').innerHTML = (tspo + tspo5 + tspo10);
document.getElementById('biscash').innerHTML = (tbis + tbis5 + tbis10);
document.getElementById('arkcash').innerHTML = (tark + tark5 + tark10);
document.getElementById('mercash').innerHTML = (tmer + tmer5 + tmer10);
alert(13);
document.getElementById('totalcash').innerHTML = totalc;

}
function onClick3(){
    var iso2 = document.getElementById('uisoa').value;
    var meg2 = document.getElementById('umega').value;
    var mex2 = document.getElementById('umexa').value;
    var mor2 = document.getElementById('umora').value;
    var noc2 = document.getElementById('unoca').value;
    var pye2 = document.getElementById('upyea').value;
    var tri2 = document.getElementById('utria').value;
    var zyd2 = document.getElementById('uzyda').value;

    iso = iso.replace(1, iso2);
    meg = meg.replace(1, meg2);
    mex = mex.replace(1, mex2);
    mor = mor.replace(1, mor2);
    noc = noc.replace(1, noc2);
    pye = pye.replace(1, pye2);
    tri = tri.replace(1, tri2);
    zyd = zyd.replace(1, zyd2);

}
function onClick2() {
    var e = document.getElementById('admin');
    var a = prompt("Password");
    if(a === 'admin'){
        e.style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        alert('Incorrect password');
    }
}
alert(14);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning variable wrong way

```
var iso = "<?php = $isop; ?>";
```

use like this

```
var iso = "<?php echo $isop; ?>";
```

or

```
var iso = "<?= $isop; ?>";
```